# How do I get the nested data from JSON AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I want to get the average rating from the Reviews and display it but I'm unsure on how to do it.

JSON

```
"Reviews":[
    {
      "OwnerID":1,
      "Comment": "Charlotte is brilliant. A lovely person. Thank you!",
      "rating":4
    },
    {
      "OwnerID":2,
      "Comment": "The best dog carer ever! She is amazing",
      "rating":4
    }
  ],
```

html file

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in PetCareProfile>
    <span ng-repeat="rate in item.Reviews" class="item-text-wrap"> {{calculateAverage(rate.rating)}} </span>
</ion-item>
```

Controller

```
.controller('CareTakerProfileCtrl',
function($scope,$http,$stateParams,$ionicPopup, ionicDatePicker) 
{
    $http.get('js/SampleJson.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.PetCareProfile = data.PetCareTakers;
    $scope.whichPetCareProfile = $stateParams.aId;

    $scope.calculateAverage = function(MyData){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < MyData.length; i++){
      sum += parseInt(MyData[i], 10); //don't forget to add the base
    }

    var avg = sum/MyData.length;

  return avg;
};
})
```

Result:
NaN NaN NaN

What I wanted:
4.3333333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the array to function and calculate the average using angular.forEach()

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in PetCareProfile">
         {{calculateAverage(item)}} 
 </li>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.PetCareProfile = [{
      "Reviews": [{
        "OwnerID": 1,
        "Comment": "Charlotte is brilliant. A lovely person. Thank you!",
        "rating": 4
      }, {
        "OwnerID": 2,
        "Comment": "The best dog carer ever! She is amazing",
        "rating": 4
      }]
    }]; // 
  
    $scope.loopcount = 0;
    $scope.calculateAverage = function(MyData) {
      $scope.sum = 0;
      var filterData = MyData.Reviews;
      angular.forEach(filterData, function(val) {
        $scope.sum += val.rating;
      });
      var avg = $scope.sum / filterData.length;
      return avg;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in PetCareProfile">
         {{calculateAverage(item)}} 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. However, item.rating doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can i see your controller?

Comment: Hi there I have just updated my question and added my controller

Comment: Sorry no :( I dont have teamviewer

Comment: @JoshSoh check the demo

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, it worked! However, it caused another problem. The result displayed 3 times because of the loop but I only want one result. Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: let me modify the sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132310/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-josh-soh).

Comment: But without ng-repeat how can I get the average?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in PetCareProfile>
    {{item.rating}}
</ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

but if you want (only in IONIC) you can use also (instead of ng-repeat)

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in PetCareProfile">
    {{item.rating}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. However, item.rating doesn't seem to work.

Comment: sorry maybe try with tem.Reviews.rating

Comment: I've tried with item.Reviews.rating however the value only comes out when I put it as item.Reviews[1].rating. I don't want a individual number but a array of the rating.

Comment: ah ok ..so try to do or a double ng-rpeat or just try with ng-repeat="item in PetCareProfile.Reviews

Comment: Hi there it worked when I put a double ng-repeat. However, the data shows "4,4,5" although I wanted it to be the average of them